# FaceBook PHP API SDK: suddenly the argument 'link' is not published and /me/feed is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I completed this script, that was working fine till this morning, when launching it, suddenly I noticed that the argument `"link"` of the array `$linkData`, is not published any longer, (no error returned) while `"message"` is published.

I also noticed that if I put `/me/feed` into the object `$fb->post`, it doesn't work (see the commented line). No errors returned.

While, if I put the code of a group (the code you see is a test group I created to test the script), the argument `"message"` is published (not the `"link"`)

The scopes are:

```
user_managed_groups,
user_events,
user_friends,
user_posts,
publish_actions,
user_actions.music,
user_actions.video,
public_profile
```

The link is referred to the link for which the application is written. the `www.example.com` URL, is written here for this example. In the real code, I use the URL of the site of the App (that till yesterday was working fine).

Please here the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

define(__APP_ID__, XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
define(__APP_SECRET__, 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY');
define(__APP_TOKEN__, 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ');
define(__APP_ACCESS_TOKEN__, 'WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW');

require_once '../include/setup.php';
require_once $root_dir.'/include/Facebook/autoload.php';

// Creates the object
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => __APP_ID__,
    'app_secret' => __APP_SECRET__,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$linkData = [
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com',
    'message' => 'The link above, is not any longer published',
];

$group_id = "1041863359178529";

        try {

            //$response = $fb->post("/me/feed", $linkData, __APP_ACCESS_TOKEN__); // SUDDENLY it doesn't work any longer
            $response = $fb->post("/{$group_id}/feed", $linkData, __APP_ACCESS_TOKEN__);

            } catch  (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
                echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
                echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }

        $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
        echo 'Posted with id: ' . $graphNode['id']."\r\n";

?>
```

EDIT:
Is there anything I can do? Is id depending from the App settings? I changed many parameters to find a solution but I still have the issue.

Comment: The `example.com` domain was blocked by Facebook’s security mechanism for a while today. (By now, it should work again.)

Comment: Hi CBRoe. I wrote here example.com just in the script here to avoid to make advertising of the site in which I'm working for. However the real domain, in the script I use, is at the place of example.com, and it's the same domain declared for the App itself.
In the day of today, I noticed that /me/feed is back working. but in groups the link is not published at all. And I have not clue if it's my fault or else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did verified that the block, is due FB.
In other words: probably of security reasons (mainly Anti-Spam), FB block repetitive use of the function in short time.

I did try also to wait more than 15 seconds among the iterations, but if I employ it for more than 20-25 time in one day, FB suspends all the required authorizations.

At the time I did post the thread, FB was enabling only the post of the text, and deactivated OpenGraph.

Now, instead, it blocks any kind of sending, including text.